# c# XDocument issue

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am quite new to xml-parsing.

Following very basic tutorials I try to parse the following xml returned by a CalDav server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
 <response>
  <href>/caldav.php/icalendar.ics</href>
  <propstat>
   <prop>
    <getetag>"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"</getetag>
   </prop>
   <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
  </propstat>
 </response>
 <sync-token>data:,20</sync-token>
</multistatus>
```

Now I want to find my "response" descendants as follows:

```
Doc = XDocument.Parse(response);
foreach (var node in xDoc.Root.Descendants("response")) {
  // process node
}
```

No descendant is found. Am I missing something here? My root is indeed a "multistatus" element, it says it has elements, but it doesn't seem as they can be found by name...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: linq-to-xml being very powerful and easy to learn, it will be worthwhile to step back and also learn more about xpath and maybe even xslt - if only to appreciate linq-to-xml more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `response` element is actually in a namespace, due to this attribute in the root node:

```
xmlns="DAV:"
```

That sets the *default* namespace for that element and its descendants.

So you need to search for elements in that namespace too. Fortunately, LINQ to XML makes that really simple:

```
XNamespace ns = "DAV:";
foreach (var node in xDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "response"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This also works : xDoc.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "response")

Comment: @jdweng: Yes, but it's not as clean IMO.

Comment: Wrong!  It is cleaner because it will work with any ns.  Your solution will only work with a namespace of DAV.

Comment: @jdweng: My solution finds precisely the elements desired, and no others. I think that's a good thing. I like being specific about what I'm looking for. The OP could change it to use "the namespace of the root element" if they wanted, of course.

Comment: I've got a number of request from people who can get different namespaces and need a variable solution.

Comment: @jdweng: Then for *your* situation - if you really have such random and mixed  namespaces in the same document - then your solution may be appropriate. That does not make it a good *general* solution, not a good one for the OP's situation.

Comment: Not same document.  You can have a server which excepts XML from multiple clients where each client may send a different namespace.

Comment: @jdweng: Well in that case, you use the same namespace as the root element has - see the fifth comment.